# Ordering of multiple inner joins in a query to improve performance on the basis of where clause Oracle

Tags: oracle, inner-join, database-performance

I am working in oracle.

I have more than 2 tables to perform inner join. And according to me their ordering matters for query performance.

Below is the query :

```
select * from 
 FROM A a 
INNER JOIN B b
ON a.b_ID=b.id
INNER JOIN C c
ON c.id=a.c_Id
INNER JOIN D d
ON a.d_ID=d.id
INNER JOIN E e
ON e.d_id =d.id
where e.name='abc' AND e.company_name='xyz';
```

In my case I don't require full table scan of tables A, B, C, D.

I want to apply predicate filter of `name` and `company_name` to be applied first and then apply inner join of tables A,B,C,D (in execution plan).

My question is : Is that possible?

Also , If I change the order of inner join on the basis of final where clause , can that improve performance (like below query)?

```
select * from 
E e INNER JOIN D d
ON e.d_id =d.id
INNER JOIN A a
ON a.d_ID=d.id
INNER JOIN B b
ON a.b_ID=b.id
INNER JOIN C c
ON c.id=a.c_Id
where e.name='abc' AND e.company_name='xyz';
```

Even after applying this change, I found that on some DB environments, execution plan is same for two queries.

Is there any way in which I can order the steps of execution plan while query execution, like explicitly specifying the ordering of inner join?

Thanks

Comment: Best is : run te advisory, accept the best plan, and benchmark yourself, ordering  would not help, and using hints on the long run showed that the perfs will generally suffer again (their problem is that they are tied to the code, whereas the advisory is not)

Comment: Are table statistics up-to-date on all tables?

Comment: And do you have all the indexes you think in all environments, particularly on the foreign key columns?

Comment: yes,all foreign keys are indexed.

Comment: "In my case I don't require full table scan of tables A, B, C, D." -- how large are these tables (in blocks), and roughly what proportion of their rows do you need to access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @sers

I also found this solution of using `/*+ORDERED */`  earlier than the solution you provided.But I just wanted some proof of increased performace.

So I just executed

```
explain plan for sql_query;
select plan_table_output from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table',null,'typical'));
```

I cannot show the actual table output (so omitting table names) , but I will post other performance factors here :

[image]

I know that oracle can figure out the best plan , but forcing the execution plan helped me to improve performance.Also in my case this is the worst case scenario.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to go for it, you can use an optimizer hint: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10752/hintsref.htm#5555

But generally I would not recommend it - if the table statistics are up to date, the database should well be able to determine the best execution plan (especially for such an easy query).